# Couldn't Display [program] -- No application installed for "shared library" files

Tags: permissions, filemanager, chmod, executable, shared-library

I think the problem is -- to Ubuntu, it doesn't seem that some of the files are executable at all or rather it doesn't know its file to type. The Files Manager due to which instead of showing the original icon (let's say the *Arduino icon* in this case) always tends to show some sort of *unexecutable* icon (as is visible in the attached image) for almost every (downloaded) file/program.

So, when I double click the file (say Arduino-ide) I get the message '**there is no application installed for "shared library" files.**'

**Note 1:** I can mostly *run* the files/programs from the *terminal* with `./` and it works mostly correctly but that's not the permanent solution at all.

So, is it because some application/package is missing since I've done *minimal installation* of Ubuntu?!

**Note 2:** I've already tried `chmod +x`, `chmod 777`, and permissions tab of file's properties in Files (which probably uses `chmod` anyway) but nothing seemed to work.

**Note 3:** Also, for the (unreadable) icon problem, I've tried creating **Desktop Entry** (altering `Exec`, `Path`, `Icon` in the new, created text file) as was suggested in some of the other answers but that didn't work as well.

Here's the image [image]

**Note 4:** I know a few other similar questions exist but none of them have been able to resolve my situation as of now.

Comment: Have you tried to go to **Edit → Preferences → Behavior** and toggle **Executable Text Files** to **Ask each time** as described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/861730/167115)?

Answer (score 0):

Execute the file using terminal.

```
user@ubuntu:~/Applications/arduino-ide_2.0.1_Linux_64bit$ ./arduino-ide
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).